# Add horizontal crosshair to d3.js chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I am successful in getting crosshair in D3.js chart but issue is I am only getting vertical line, how do I add code for horizontal line as well? 
[Image of chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFAdB.png)
[image]

[JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/1g3u15L7/) chart is not plotting in JSFiddle

Basically code to add vertical line crosshair is as below:-

```
 var vertical = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "remove")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "19")
        .style("width", "1px")
        .style("height", "450px")
        .style("top", "47px")
        .style("bottom", "1px")
        .style("left", "8px")
        .style("background", "#000");
```

Can I add horizontal crosshair as well same way?

P.S. also wanted a way to keep this vertical line only in chart area, but is coming in whole body, i.e. empty area next to chart in right and left.

Answer (score 10):

Your approach is too complicated. This is simpler:

First, create a transparent rectangle to get the mouse movements:

```
var transpRect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("opacity", 0);
```

Then, create the lines:

```
var verticalLine = svg.append("line")
    .attr("opacity", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("y2", height)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("pointer-events", "none");

var horizontalLine = svg.append("line")
    .attr("opacity", 0)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("pointer-events", "none");
```

Finally, position the lines on `mousemove`:

```
transpRect.on("mousemove", function(){  
    mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    mousex = mouse[0];
    mousey = mouse[1];
    verticalLine.attr("x1", mousex).attr("x2", mousex).attr("opacity", 1);
    horizontalLine.attr("y1", mousey).attr("y2", mousey).attr("opacity", 1)
}).on("mouseout", function(){  
    verticalLine.attr("opacity", 0);
    horizontalLine.attr("opacity", 0);
});
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xrf1ro1a/

PS: to avoid killing your tooltips, I put the `mousemove` both on the rectangle and on the svg as well, which has the undesirable effect of making the lines going outside the chart area. To avoid this, set `pointer-events = none` to the elements outside the chart area.